# Can you move files to a gcloud VM instance with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

With Python you can move files to a storage bucket but I'm pretty sure you cannot do this to a VM instance.  Seems rather ridiculous that you can do one but not the other. I have 93,000 files and I can only move 1/4th of them at a time.  Plus I need to gzip all of them before I move them, then delete them.  Do all of this I need to program this in Python.  Further, I reformatted my current external harddrive to a different format (the one that works for Mac, Linux and Windows) and now I basically cannot moves files around in it with GUI but have to move them with command line or Python.  I'm going to try to get Python to execute terminal commands if that is possible or maybe write an echo problem.  If anyone knows of easier workaround please let me know.  Again, my most important question is whether one can use Python to move files from the personal laptop to a gcloud VM instance.

Comment: There are several libraries that support copying files to computers using SSH/SFTP in Python, Go, Java, C#, etc. There are many examples on the Internet. Your method of using subprocess to run `gcloud` is not a good idea. Too many dependencies on the environment being set up for `gcloud`. Remember that `gcloud` is a Python script and not a program binary.

Comment: Cool, tell me more.  Do you know of any library in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable workaround.  The `subprocess` module works as a good substitute for command line in Python.  They don't make this very clear in the documentation but you have to put the arguments as a list of strings as the first argument when you call the subprocess class, like so:

```
import subprocess
str1 = '/volumes/iweb/as_lists/61.pkl'
subprocess.run(['gcloud','compute','scp',str1,'your_instance@instance-4:/mnt/disks/temp_dir/61.pkl'])
```

So the `gcloud` command takes 4 arguments and each have to be put in the list which is the first argument of the `subprocess.run` class.